# Google Cloud Deploy is failing on step 0

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, cicd, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-deploy

I am using Google Cloud Build to build the artifacts and deploy to GKE using gcloud deploy command in the cloud build as the final step by passing the build artifacts to it from the previous step.
The cloud deploy starts the deployment process by calling cloud build again and fails immediately with an error: "building helm dependencies: exit status 1" and without further explanations.

[image]

Comment: are you sure of the service account’s permissions? Can you share the content of the step its failing at?

Comment: There was some permission issues earlier which I fixed earlier. Here there is no description of permission error. FYI, I am separating projects by environment and a common project for ci-cd. I am trying to deploy to staging project from the ci-cd project here.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Skaffold returns this error "building helm dependencies: exit status 1" when it doesn't have access to Kubernetes. So the issue with Cloud Deploy can be access issue to the specified Kubernetes cluster.